# Quick Look Generator iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to extend the Quick Look Framework on iOS to handle an unknown file type like on Mac? I don't want to have to switch to my app to preview the file, much like viewing image files in email or iMessage. I would like to remove the step of having to select what app to use to open the file.

On Mac they call it a Quick Look Generator, but I can't find a way to do it on iOS

Answer (score 2):

This is how you use **Quick Look Framework** in iOS

**Xcode 8.3.2. Swift 3**

First goto Build Phases and add new framework **QuickLook.framework** under Link Binary with Libraries.

Next **import QuickLook** in your ViewController Class

Next set delegate method of QuickLook to your ViewController class to access all the methods of QUickLook.framework (see below).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
    }
```

Next create instance of QLPreviewController in your class as below:

let quickLookController = QLPreviewController()

Now set datasource in your viewdidload method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        quickLookController.dataSource = self
}
```

Now create an **fileURLs** array to store all the documents path which you need to pass later to QLPreviewController via delegate methods.

```
var fileURLs = [URL]()
```

Now add below methods to your class to tell QLPreviewController about your total number of documents.

```
func numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController(controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return fileURLs.count
        }

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            return fileURLs[index] as QLPreviewItem
        }

@available(iOS 4.0, *)
func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return fileURLs.count
        }
```

Finally the method which shows your docs. You can also check if the type of document you want to Preview is possible to preview or not as below.

```
func showMyDocPreview(currIndex:Int) {

        if QLPreviewController.canPreview(fileURLs[currIndex] as QLPreviewItem) {
            quickLookController.currentPreviewItemIndex = currIndex
            navigationController?.pushViewController(quickLookController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have data, not the URLs so how to show it? I get this error for passing base64 pdf data:
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x2079d5f90) to 'QLPreviewItem'

Answer (score 1):

For now, if you want to show a preview of a file of a type not handled by the standard QLPreviewController, you have to write something yourself in your own app. You cannot write a custom Quick Look plugin like you can on the Mac.