# Open PDF file using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I add a **PDF file** for an app , where you click on a button to view the file & when you're done you get back to screen you were at?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you simply want to view a PDF file you can load it into a UIWebView.

```
let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
```

**Swift 4.1 :**

```
let url: URL! = URL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf")
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

If you'd like to achieve more, a good framework is [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/).

Comment: UIWebView can load a local PDF. Instead use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURLPath];` . . the path will be either your documents directory or your resource bundle. . There's also a method on UIWebView to load data, so you could feed it an NSData object. (Streaming from file is probably better for memory usage though).

Comment: If in resources directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios (similar story for documents dir). . . build NSURL from string.

Comment: is  PSPDFKit suggested by Jasper is free?

Comment: I've never tried it, but heard it is popular. On the website it looks like its a paid product, however the actual price is not clear!

Comment: Starting in iOS 8.0 and OS X 10.10, use WKWebView to add web content to your app. Do not use UIWebView or WebView.

Comment: @MosTwanTedT Feel free to edit the answer with current best approach 

Answer (score 69):

**Apple added [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) framework in `iOS 11`**

Add a UIView to your view controller and make it's class to PDFView

[image]

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var pdfView: PDFView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf") {
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
                pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfView.autoScales = true
                pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
                pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 4 display modes : `singlePage`, `singlePageContinuous`, `twoUp`, `twoUpContinuous` .

Comment: Error inside Xcode 10.2, need to put method inside viewDidAppear()

Comment: It doesn't necessary need to specify custom class for view `@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: UIView!`

Answer (score 26):

***SWIFT 4+***

*If has to open file from local cache/Documentdiectory which has file path*

**Method 1: using UIDocumentInteractionController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
   //let path =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Guide", ofType: ".pdf")!
    let dc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    dc.delegate = self
    dc.presentPreview(animated: true)
}

//MARK: UIDocumentInteractionController delegates
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self//or use return self.navigationController for fetching app navigation bar colour
}
```

**Method 2: using WebView**

```
let webview = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
view.addSubview(webview)
webview.navigationDelegate = self
webview.load(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)))//URL(string: "http://") for web URL
```

Comment: You can share with iBook

Answer (score 18):

**For Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.0**

Save the PDF file in any folder of your xcode.
Suppose the file name is 'Filename.pdf'

```
if let pdf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Filename", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
    let req = NSURLRequest(url: pdf)
    yourWebViewOutletName.loadRequest(req as URLRequest)        
}
```

Same will apply if you want to open any html file.

Answer (score 14):

Check out [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/241/) from IOS11

Here is an example of a view controller which implements PDFView from PDFKit.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Add PDFView to view controller.
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(pdfView)

        // Fit content in PDFView.
        pdfView.autoScales = true

        // Load Sample.pdf file.
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample", withExtension: "pdf")
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

you can use UIDocumentInteractionController to preview file in IOS. 
In the view controller's file, add a property of type UIDocumentInteractionController

and implement a simple delegate method of it

```
self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(URL: url)
self.documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
self.documentInteractionController?.presentPreviewAnimated(t‌​rue) 

func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    return self
}
```

don't forget to add `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` in view controller's class

Comment: self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(URL: url)
        self.documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
        self.documentInteractionController?.presentPreviewAnimated(true)

Comment: It's useless in this case. "Preview" should be used for preview - in small views, but not for "opening" pdf.

Answer (score 11):

**SWIFT 5**

An update to open the file from the *Document* directory (device) and present preview:

```
let urlFile = URL(string: pathToFile)
var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController!    
documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: urlFile!)
documentInteractionController?.delegate = self
documentInteractionController?.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

And UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate:

```
extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}
```

If you want to dismiss the document preview you can use:

```
documentInteractionController?.dismissPreview(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this `UIViewController`. It contains the `share button` for free:

```swift
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class PDFWebViewController: UIViewController {
    var pdfURL: URL!
    
    private var pdfView: PDFView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
                
        self.setPDFView()
        self.fetchPDF()
    }
    
    private func setPDFView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
            
            self.pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 3;
            self.pdfView.minScaleFactor = self.pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit;
            self.pdfView.autoScales = true;
            self.pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
            
            self.view.addSubview(self.pdfView)
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchPDF() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: self.pdfURL), let document = PDFDocument(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pdfView.document = document
                    self.addShareBarButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addShareBarButton() {
        let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action,
                                            target: self,
                                            action: #selector(self.presentShare))
        barButtonItem.tintColor = .white
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
    }
    
    @objc private func presentShare() {
        guard let pdfDocument = self.pdfView.document?.dataRepresentation() else { return }
        
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfDocument], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

To use it:

```swift
let viewController = PDFWebViewController()

// the url can be a web url or a file url
viewController.pdfURL = url
        
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: It just awesome answer for me. +1

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code in Swift 4

1. Import PDFKit
2. Copy this code

   ```
   let pdfView = PDFView()        
   pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.addSubview(pdfView)

   pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
   pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
   pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
   pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

   guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }

   if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
       pdfView.document = document
   }
   ```

Comment: How to close once the document is opened?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Quick Look Framework from Apple.

It is very flexible.

You can show your PDF file with zoom feature.

Also you have support for all other types (like png, jpg, docx, txt, rtf, xlsx, zip, mov, etc) of files and it is very easy to use.

Please refer 

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46541142/5032981) answer if you want detail description of using QuickLook.framework

Answer (score 2):

A modernized version of Akila's answer, with the benefit that it is a drop in, ready to use `UIViewController` that you can integrate into your app.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

final class PDFViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: view.frame)
        
        title = "Your_title_here"
        
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "document_name_here", withExtension: "pdf"),
            let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
            
            view.addSubview(pdfView)
        }
    }
}
```

- It creates the `PDFView` during `viewDidLoad` and sets it to use the view's frame
- The `URL` for the PDF file is safely unwrapped from the bundle and then a `PDFDocument` is created, if possible
- Some common settings are used. Adjust as needed
- Finally, it adds the `PDFView` as a subview of the controller's `view`

Answer (score 1):

//In Swift 5

```
    class PDFBookViewController: UIViewController, PDFViewDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addPDFView()  
    }
    
    private func addPDFView() {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pdfContenerView.addSubview(pdfView)
    
        pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContenerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContenerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContenerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pdfContenerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        
        ///Open pdf with help of FileManager URL
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let bookWithPdf = "\(bookname).pdf"
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(bookWithPdf)
            let document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)
            pdfView.document = document
        } 
  @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let url: URL = URL(string: "http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf") {
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url)) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let openLink = NSURL(string : OtherContactorProfileVview.Result.CertificateList[index].CertificateFileLink)

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: openLink! as URL)
    present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    let port = UIStoryboard(
        name: "Main",
        bundle: nil
    ).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFViewer") as! PDFViewer
    port.strUrl = OtherContactorProfileVview.Result.CertificateList[index].CertificateFileLink
    navigationController?.pushViewController(port, animated: true)
}
```