# IOS PDF Viewer?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am looking for an IOS PDF viewer for a Swift iPad application I am working on. Using UI Web View does not really have enough functionality that I need for the app to work smoothly. Here is what I need:

- Search in the Document (not necessary)
- Jump to a page
- Download to local storage
- Update to newest version when connected to the internet

I understand that not all of these have to do with the actual PDF viewer, but I listed them because they will eventually need to work with the PDF viewer. I am very reluctant to try and use one of the many PDF viewers that are out there, because I am looking for something that looks professional and is pretty simple.

Should I use a PDF viewer kit or try to customize the UI Web View a little bit? I am not sure what to do in this situation. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Library requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question is related and might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883816/open-pdf-file-using-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use [M13PDFKit](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13PDFKit). Its quite easy and have more functionalities such as thumbnails view and swipe to right.

Your code would be simple as

```
// get main viewer controller
let viewerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PDFChildViewController") as! PDFChildViewController

// pass the file path / string url
let document = PDFKDocument(contentsOfFile: filePath , password: nil)
viewerController.loadDocument(document)

// present
self.presentViewController(viewerController, animated: true, completion: { 
    // do something when start present the pdf
})
```

Comment: Small comment, you shouldn't have to specify the type `PDFKDocument` - the compiler should be able to infer the type with just `let document = PDFKDocument(...)`

Comment: @Kevin thanks, update that

Comment: i tried with cocoapod,how to import mupdf in swift project,if i am using xib not storyboard

Comment: is there a way to use this, but with a uitabviewcontroller? (i want this to be one of the tabs)

Answer (score 10):

I think your best bet is [Quick Look Framework from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html). It is extremely smooth and easy to use. You can have a list of many documents and switch between them while previewing document. Moreover, it is the viewer used everywhere in iOS, so **users are already familiar with it** and it comes with all basic functionalities (zoom, select, copy/paste, ...).

A good tutorial is [Using Quick Look Framework for Previewing Documents with Swift](https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/).