# Display PDF file in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        docController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(urlVal!))
        docController.delegate = self
        docController.presentPreview(animated: true)       
    }


    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return self
     }
}
```

Above code I'm not able to display the pdf file. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is your docController defined? I can't see it in the above code.

Comment: Hi, i define at the top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open PDF file using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883816/open-pdf-file-using-swift)

Answer (score 6):

By seeing your code it seems that you missed to add **UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate** delegate method.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController,UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

           var docController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(urlVal!))
            docController.delegate = self
            docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
        }
        func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return self
        }
    }
```

**OR**

You can also view PDF by loading it into **WKWebView**.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pdfFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "iostutorial", withExtension: "pdf")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: pdfFilePath!)
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView.load(request)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

    }
```

[image]

Comment: ...sorry i miss out to adding here..so sorry..
i got add the func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview actually

Comment: cant assign value of type WKWebView to type UIWebView!

Comment: Yes you can do that by using this code.
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let pdfFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "iostutorial", withExtension: "pdf")
            let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: pdfFilePath!)
            let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
            webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
            self.view.addSubview(webView)
            
        }

Comment: i hit error 
Thread1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
at let urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: pdfFilePath!)

Comment: Actually it's working code in my project, All you need to do is just replace your PDF file path.

Comment: dunnoe why i hit Thread1 : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Can you share me your pdf url?

Comment: http://www.finexuscards.com/wp-content/themes/finexuscards/pdf/FINEXUS-Cards-Privacy-Statement.pdf

Comment: Using above code i am able to load your PDF, Make sure you enable app transport security key into your plist file.

Comment: how to do that ? please guild me

Comment: Is App Transport Security Setting -> Allow Arbitrary Loads  ??

Comment: Yes add this key value.
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are missing the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate implementation. For preview, you should implement this method

```
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController
```

Return which ViewController need to display the Preview. If you pass the self View Controller it will display the PDF preview in the existing view controller modally. Just do this one in your View controller if you want to display the preview in the same controller.

```
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
```

**If you are already doing this in your code, there is high chance of PDF URL path might be wrong.**

Comment: i already doing this but the pdf still cant show..the pdf get from one URL from DB

Comment: ok. Download the PDF file from the URL  and pass the file url path to the DocumentInteractionController.

Comment: But..i need to use URL to get the pdf file oh

Comment: right. write the pdf content to a file  in your app's Documents folder. Get the file URL from that file.

Comment: ya..currently i get from DB the URL

Comment: You have the PDF url but no PDF content. You should download the PDF Content from that URL (URL from DB) and write to the file and pass that file url to DocumentInteractionController.

Comment: which mean..inside my program need have the pdf file ?

Comment: ...if i download the pdf and upload to my project..after that i do 
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myPDF", ofType: "pdf")

Comment: ok. Check this out on how to download and save the file in iOS app bundle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323427/how-do-i-download-and-save-a-file-locally-on-ios-using-objective-c

Comment: how to do that ? please guild me

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Quicklook framework instead, it supports a wide range of document types:

- iWork documents
- Microsoft Office documents
- PDF files
- Images
- Text files
- Rich-Text Format documents
- Comma-Separated Value files (csv)

Supports sharing of the relevant documents as well and is easy to implement.

Follow this tutorial on how to do it in Swift: https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

Import this framework

```
import SafariServices
```

Then call this sentences whenever you need

```
if let url = URL(string: "YOUR_PDF_URL") {
  let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
  config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

  let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
  present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

The code will present a Safari view with the pdf on it.