# how to view pdf files in collectionview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, pdf, view, uicollectionview

I created an app with pdf files in resources and I want to view them in the collectionView of the app like icons I tried to make an array of the pdf files but it didn't work I am so beginner at this and this is may be my first question in stackOverFlow please can you help?

I have created a library of PDF files and want the user to display them and read them after downloading the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to implement the PDFKit framework in your app. This framework has been available since IOS 11.

Create an extra class in you project called "PDFView" and assign the CollectionViewCell (in which you are trying to display the PDF) to this class. Then you can setup the loading of the PDF file in your newly created "PDFView" class.

For more information over the implementation please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883816/open-pdf-file-using-swift).